# carousel property to slide more than one content using carousel.js and prototype.js

Tags: carousel

I am using `carousel.js` to slide content (manufacturers image).
Currently it is sliding only one image after a few seconds.

I want to know if there is any property in the `carousel.js` that like I can specify number of images to slide.

The script used to slide:

```
new Carousel('carousel-wrapper-manuf', $$('#carousel-content-manuf .slide'), $$('a.carousel-control'), 
    {
        duration: 0.2,
        visibleSlides : 6,                              
        circular: true,  
        wheel: true,
        auto: true
    }
);
```

Comment: This is more of a google question, really :P

Comment: i tried it but this carousel is too old.